# Angular2 + Material: mat-toolbar casts no shadow over mat-sidenav-container despite mat-elevation-z*

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

Trying to mimic the look of the [Material guide](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/api), I can't get the toolbar's shadow to be rendered atop the mat-sidenav-container element:

Page showing toolbar and sidenav, but drop shadow isn't visible:

[image]

Page showing the toolbar alone, the shadow is rendered:

[image]

See the HTML code, it can't be more simple. What am I missing? Thanks...

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z6" color="primary">
  toolbar
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container >

  <!-- Side menu -->
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">

    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <ul>

      <!-- Home (aka dashboard) -->
      <li>
        <a routerLink="/">dashboard</a>
      </li>

      <!-- Home (aka dashboard) -->
      <li>
        <a routerLink="/resolutions">resolutions</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- List resolutions -->
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>incentive</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <!-- Routed contents -->
  <div class="contents">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

had the exact same issue.
I resolved it by adding the following class in my CSS:

```
.sidenav-container {
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

and added it to the mat-sidenav-container

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
...
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: good job for the negative z-index. Fixed my case as long as the toolbar has a z-index property as well. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, setting -1 for the z-index deactivates all the possible user interaction with the content. The buttons in the sidenav are not clickable anymore. Are you having the same issue?

Comment: Ok, was able to fix it by applying a z-index really big on the toolbar instead of the sidenav-container

Comment: @JacquesBourque How did you fix it? I have the same issue.

Comment: @yuro I've set the z-index to `9999` for the toolbar. But I removed it since it was causing other issues (if I remember correctly...  been a while :) )

Comment: @yuro I just started another project and I did the `z-index: 9999` trick and it is working.. hope this helps!

Comment: with angular 12.0.2 I just set the toolbar to have a z-index: 2 to avoid click issues with the sidebar

Comment: You should always minimize usage of any !important statements in your css. This will often make things ugly and lead to problems in the future. Anyway, you have a white background on white page, that means a better and easier solution without any !important statements would be to just make the background transparent, so it won't overlay the shadow with white color.

Answer (score 26):

Add this in your styles:

```
.mat-toolbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Only working answer without weird side-effects for me in 2020

Comment: Quoting @Spikolynn 's reply! Working without side effects.

Comment: It's quite said, that this is the solution in 2021. Thanks @alex-nepsha

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
CSS:

.tbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Then in my template:

```
HTML:
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z6 tbar">
  ...
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 3):

If changing the z-index doesn't work, add the following class:

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z2"></mat-toolbar>
```

As per the angular guide: (https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation)

Comment: This works for me on Angular 15

Answer (score 2):

I think changing z-index is not optimal. Better solution is to just add transparent background to your sidenav components.

```
mat-sidenav-container {
   background: transparent;
   
   mat-sidenav {
      background: transparent; // that one is also necessary if you have mode="side" on your mat-sidenav element
   }
}
```

Worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

not been able to test but. I had a similar sounding issue with cards not looking elevated. I just need to pad them out from the hard left.

```
<mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="true" style="margin: 10px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
.sidenav-container {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a class `.mat-drawer-container` (You need to search in your CSS files because if you have a background defined, this layer will overload your shadow navbar)

You need to set `.mat-drawer-container` background as "none"

```css
.mat-drawer-container {
  background: none !important;
}
```

This will solve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Do not give `z-index:-1` on `mat-sidenav-container`. Better give elevation to toolbar -

```
mat-toolbar {
z-index:100;
position:sticky;
}
```